# How to Integrate AngularMaterial with Ionic3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, angular-material, ionic-material

I have a Question that how to integrate Angular4Material in Ionic3.
I am looking to use AngularMaterial (https://material.angular.io/) in Ionic3 Project.

**I know that Ionic3 Already comes with Material Design**,but few components were not good in Ionic3 especially **Select Menu, Autocomplete** etc…
So i want to use MaterialSelect Menu https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview

Autocomplete [https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview1](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview)

from AngularMaterial?

I tried to integrate this in my project. But not working.

Previously in Angular1Material and Ionic1 combo its working.
But in Ionic3 How to Achieve This?

Please help me on this.

If its worked means we can give awesome designs using AngularMaterial compare to ionic material.
Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work?

Comment: Actually i just tried with material button but it didnt worked out.
just its displaying normal button

Comment: Have you imported all the required dependencies and included the styles?

Comment: I done like below

1.npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk
2.npm install --save @angular/animations

     Module.ts file
 import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

 @NgModule({
   ...
   imports: [BrowserAnimationsModule],
   ...
 })
 
 added 
 in home.html file added 
 <button mat-button>Click me!</button>
 i dont know what to add in home.ts file regarding to this button modules.

Comment: You also need `import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';` in your app.module